# Spare meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

As far as I know, **spare** means *extra or more than you need*.
With that being said, what would be the meaning of "spare diet" in the following sentence?

> To content myself with a **spare** diet

I can't understand someone **contenting** himself with extra food!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question, because it highlights one of those cases (which I'm sure must be *very annoying* to English learners) where a word can mean two different, opposite things.

The [meanings of the word **spare**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spare) which are intended here are:

> **4** : healthily lean
>
> **5** : not abundant or plentiful

In other words, the author is saying they are putting up with a **frugal** or minimal (rather than plentiful) diet. You are right that this is, in some sense, the opposite of the more common meanings:

> **1** : not being used
>
> **2** : being over and above what is needed

Comment: Or it could be a typo of *sparse* to mean scant or meager? (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sparse)